# Sync Sony Smartband data to own Server

Tags: android, google-apps, fitness

I just played arround with the Sony Smartband SWR30.

It's only usable with a Sony Network or Google Account including a public Google+ Account (I don't want to add Google+ to my Google Account).

I also discovered that Sony is publishing aggregated statistics which I don't agree with.

I need an app, that let's me sync the data to my own server.
I can do the server part without a problem, but I am not able to code apps, nor can I find one.